# how to select the desired area in google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, python, google-earth-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEtNZ.jpg)
I need to calculate the area of ​​this coal cut, is there a way to avoid tracing it by hand?

I tried to do this manually, but there is too much work, and I need to select several such areas. Help me please!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.